# How to dynamically connect to a serial port based on `lsusb` so that the devices connect to the right thing

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, pyserial

stack overflow,

I've spent a good part of today trying to dynamically connect different USB peripherals based on the response from 'lsusb' in python. The goal is to allow a device to be unplugged and plugged back into the raspberry pi and the software automatically reconnects.

Right now I have this snippet of code:

```py
def __init__(self, timeout = 1):
        self.data = {}
        
        #ports = ['/dev/ttyACM1','/dev/ttyACM0','/dev/ttyAMA0']
        device_re = re.compile(b"Bus\s+(?P<bus>\d+)\s+Device\s+(?P<device>\d+).+ID\s(?P<id>\w+:\w+)\s(?P<tag>.+)$", re.I)
        df = subprocess.check_output("lsusb")
        devices = []
        for i in df.split(b'\n'):
            if i:
                info = device_re.match(i)
                if info:
                    dinfo = info.groupdict()
                    dinfo['device'] = '/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s' % (dinfo.pop('bus'), dinfo.pop('device'))
                    devices.append(dinfo)
        print(devices)
        
        if devices in ["Boron']:
# How to connect to the port this is connected to? 
#         for p in ports:
#             try:
#                 self.p = serial.Serial(p, 115200, timeout = timeout, stopbits=1 )
#                 print("Connected Outlet on,", p)
#                 break
#             except:
#                 print(p,'Taken')
```

I get a json structure:

```json
 Foundation 3.0 root hub', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'002'/b'001'"}, {'id': b'17ef:608d', 'tag': b'Lenovo Optical Mouse', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'006'"}, {'id': b'17ef:6099', 'tag': b'Lenovo Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'011'"}, {'id': b'2b04:c00d', 'tag': b'Particle Boron CDC Mode', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'013'"}, {'id': b'2184:0065', 'tag': b'GW Instek GPM-8310 Virtual ComPort', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'012'"}, {'id': b'0bc8:5880', 'tag': b'Telmax Communications USB Camera', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'010'"}, {'id': b'0bda:5411', 'tag': b'Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'009'"}, {'id': b'2109:3431', 'tag': b'VIA Labs, Inc. Hub', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'002'"}, {'id': b'1d6b:0002', 'tag': b'Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub', 'device': "/dev/bus/usb/b'001'/b'001'"}]
```

I want to connect to `Particle Boron` device each time it's mounted and dismounted during a programing script.

How would I search the array to then connect to the correct serail port each time it runs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer your question directly, but instead would like to propose an easier alternative.

How other's usually go about this, is to ensure that a device always gets mapped to the file upon being inserted. That way you do not have to dynamically determine anything, which greatly simplifies your setup.

You can achieve this with udev rules. in your case something like this would probably work:

```
echo 'ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2b04", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c00d", SYMLINK+="boron"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-boron.rules
```

the idVendor and idProduct were taken from your lsusb output and thats who udev knows to map that device to /dev/boron.

With this you can get rid of all your code to dynamically get the device file. Just juse /dev/boron and if it is not connected, the file won't be there.